# text files vs database

Tags: java, programming

We have a sign-out program that was created in python. We would like to make the same program as an android app. Presently the main screen has a series of category buttons. When you click on a category, it opens a text file with a list of items for that category and creates a button for each item in a new window. When you click on one of the items it takes you to sign-out screen, which then adds the sign-out info to a text file that records a date/time stamp. Since no one here has created an Android app before, we would like to know 1) if we can we use the existing text files in Java or do we need to use a database program 2) we want to capture a human signature, is that stored in a database program or do we need a different type of program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert an image into a blob field in a database, that image being the signature.

You are better off using a database.  You can sort,organize, group, and do many things to the data when its in a database.

You can of course open and read and write text files, but the added features of database are compelling.

Comment: Can you use Excel or do you need a program like SQLite or MySQL?

Comment: While you could link an ODBC to an excel spreadsheet, your better off with mariadb (non oracle mysql).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. We like supporting open source software.